# C Read a column of a line from file

Tags: c, file, fgets, fread, scanf

I am reading /proc/diskstats (you may or may not know it) but a file none the less,  which outputs many lines and some columns/fields. I'm asking if someone can show me how to retrieve the column of a line. for that small piece of data. 
Thanks.

Comment: By "column of a line" do you mean a single character?

Comment: Sorry, I mean't a string

Comment: I don't know how that file is configured, but if the string on that column has a space before it and one after, then you can tokenize the line and get your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've taken a look. the output looks like this:

> 8      17 sdb1 15 0 38 28 0 0 0 0 0 28 28

So we do have a few numbers (seem to be long integers) and we do have a string at the third place.

Now overall we can read the output line by line. For that fgets is the Standard C choice. You then can probably use sscanf to pick out the different elements. Without having it tested. something like

```
sscanf(readline, "%d%s%d....", &var1, & var2 ....
```

Should do the "trick" of that does not work a combination of you might try to read the line with strtok.

Hope that gives you an idea.